# Making one dataframe out of two dataframes as separate subcolumns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to put two data frames into one, so each one is sub column, it's not join of dataframes. So I have two dataframes, stat1_df and stat2_df and they look something like this:

```
root
 |-- max_scenes: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- median_scenes: double (nullable = false)
 |-- avg_scenes: double (nullable = true)

+----------+-------------+------------------+
|max_scenes|median_scenes|avg_scenes        |
+----------+-------------+------------------+
|97        |7.0          |10.806451612903226|
|97        |7.0          |10.806451612903226|
|97        |7.0          |10.806451612903226|
|97        |7.0          |10.806451612903226|
+----------+-------------+------------------+


root
 |-- max: double (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)

+-----+-----------+
|max  |type       |
+-----+-----------+
|10.0 |small      |
|25.0 |medium     |
|50.0 |large      |
|250.0|extra_large|
+-----+-----------+
```

, and I want the result_df to be as:

```
root
 |-- some_statistics1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max_scenes: integer (nullable = true)
      |-- median_scenes: double (nullable = false)
      |-- avg_scenes: double (nullable = true)
 |-- some_statistics2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- max: double (nullable = true)
      |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Is there any way to put those two as shown? stat1_df and stat2_df are simple dataframes, without arrays and nested columns.Final dataframe is written to mongodb. If there any additional questions I am here to answer.

Comment: How do you know which rows of stat1_df and stat2_df belong togehter?

Comment: They don't. Those are two completely different dataframes. If you take a look at schema, you can see that those two dataframes should be separate subcolumns.

Comment: In this case it is not a dataframe. A dataframe is a 2d structure which consists of rows and columns. When you show for example 5 rows of your root dataframe, you will need to show 5 rows of the sub dataframes. Maybe you want to randomly join them or create a wrapper class which holds two dataframe? Please explain your usecase. How many rows does your dataframes have?

Comment: I edited my question, so it should be clearer to you now.

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question. How do you determine whichs rows (not columns) belong togehter? How many rows do you have? Just one as in the answer below?

Comment: @cronoik, you can use some id column in both tables and join dataframe based on id

Comment: @Srinivas I am not asking for a solution, I am asking for a problem clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

Add `id` column in both `DataFrame`, move all columns into struct & then use `join` both DataFrame's

```
scala> val dfa = Seq(("10","8.9","7.9")).toDF("max_scenes","median_scenes","avg_scenes")
dfa: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max_scenes: string, median_scenes: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dfa.show(false)
+----------+-------------+----------+
|max_scenes|median_scenes|avg_scenes|
+----------+-------------+----------+
|10        |8.9          |7.9       |
+----------+-------------+----------+


scala> dfa.printSchema
root
 |-- max_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- median_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- avg_scenes: string (nullable = true)


scala> val mdfa = dfa.select(struct($"*").as("some_statistics1")).withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id)
mdfa: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [some_statistics1: struct<max_scenes: string, median_scenes: string ... 1 more field>, id: bigint]

scala> mdfa.printSchema
root
 |-- some_statistics1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- max_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- median_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- avg_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)


scala> mdfa.show(false)
+----------------+---+
|some_statistics1|id |
+----------------+---+
|[10,8.9,7.9]    |0  |
+----------------+---+


scala> val dfb = Seq(("11.2","sample")).toDF("max","type")
dfb: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max: string, type: string]

scala> dfb.printSchema
root
 |-- max: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)


scala> dfb.show(false)
+----+------+
|max |type  |
+----+------+
|11.2|sample|
+----+------+


scala> val mdfb = dfb.select(struct($"*").as("some_statistics2")).withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id)
mdfb: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [some_statistics2: struct<max: string, type: string>, id: bigint]

scala> mdfb.printSchema
root
 |-- some_statistics2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- max: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)


scala> mdfb.show(false)
+----------------+---+
|some_statistics2|id |
+----------------+---+
|[11.2,sample]   |0  |
+----------------+---+


scala> mdfa.join(mdfb,Seq("id"),"inner").drop("id").printSchema
root
 |-- some_statistics1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- max_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- median_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- avg_scenes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- some_statistics2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- max: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)


scala> mdfa.join(mdfb,Seq("id"),"inner").drop("id").show(false)
+----------------+----------------+
|some_statistics1|some_statistics2|
+----------------+----------------+
|[10,8.9,7.9]    |[11.2,sample]   |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I edited question, adding schemas of my dataframes. So if you can take a look, 'cuz they aren't nested, they are plain dataframes (talking about the difference between your example and my)

Comment: Yeah, this is closer, but problem is, I got everything under some_statistics1. Again, I edited question, where I shown examples of data. So I don't have one row per table, but 4.

Comment: Are you using above solution ?? If yes can you post output of this solution in your question ?

Comment: Yeah I was using your solution, and I got result as I needed. Thanks. (I had typo so my previous comment refers to that)